# Error due to 'S2' is not defined when get to save data to table @open_data_cube

Tags: python, sentinel-2, open-data-cube

I have a set of code blocks that ran well earlier in February to grab Sentinel-2 10 bands for the AOI using open data cube. But for some reasons I don't know, it is giving me this error message "'S2' is not defined" each time I attempted to run this cell .

```
(S2
 .mean(dim=['x','y'])
 .to_pandas()
 .median()
 .add_prefix('median_')
 .append(
     S2
     .mean(dim=['x','y'])
     .to_pandas()
     .count()
     .add_prefix('count_')
 )
)
```

How can I fix the problem in Open Data Cube? All libraries have been installed and cells ran successfully to the cell below:

```
lat, lon = (-42.510102, 147.991461)
date = '2022-01-01'
filename_out = 'test.nc'
days_before = 40
days_after = 40

try:
    S2 = get_data(lat, lon, date, days_before, days_after)
except:
    print('no data available')
```

Apparently, there is a problem with the Sentinel-2 products I am requesting to save from the data cube.

Comment: To be a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) the code that you present will need to include imports for any modules/libraries that are needed to make it run.